# Проблема с RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Выдает `NullPointerException` в `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);`.

```
   public class FragmentAcount extends Fragment {

    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public List<String> friend = new ArrayList<>();

    public FragmentAcount() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, null);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.rview);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        showFriends(v);

        return v;
    }

    private void playRecyler() {
        mAdapter = new ListFreindsAdapter(getActivity(), friend);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void showFriends(View v) {
        VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "first_name, last_name"));
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                super.onComplete(response);
                VKList list = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
                friend = new ArrayList<String>(list);
                playRecyler();
               // ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_freinds_recycler, list);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

layout file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rview"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаёте переменную, содержащую разметку, которая ещё не добавлена на экран, в асинхронный колбэк, в коем и ищете уже её. Что в этот момент происходит - одному дебаггеру известно.

Вам надо в getView инициализировать переменные, а не в асинхронном колбэке.

Т.е. переместите

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

в getView()

Comment: То есть переместить метод playRecycler в onCreateView ?

Comment: @FediaCholak, метод в методе определить нельзя, значит нельзя и перенести. Я имею в виду, что вам надо убрать из него инициализацию  RecyclerView и его LayoutManager, перенеся эти 3 строки в метод getView, а в методе playRecycler оставить только инициализацию и присвоение адаптера

Comment: Все ровно не работает...

Comment: @FediaCholak, покажите обновлённый код

Comment: Обновил. Я не совсем понял как сделать с getView, потому что не использовал его ранше.

Comment: @FediaCholak, под getView я имел в виду onCreateView. Теперь должно работать. Если у вас recyclerView переменная всё ещё null там же, то вы явно где-то опечатались. Проверьте ещё раз ту ли разметку загружаете, тот ли там ID. Попробуйте InstantRun отключить в настройках студии

Comment: Все проверил, ошибку не могу найти. ID верный, и все еще null.

Comment: А если showFriends убрать?

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Та же ошибка.

Comment: @FediaCholak, последнее что могу предложить -  `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);` Если и это не поможет... Ну, выложите на гитхаб собирающийся проект - попробую посмотреть где у вас опечатка

Comment: https://github.com/Fedia23/vk вот посмотрите.

Comment: @FediaCholak, ну, как вам и говорили у вас опечатка - вы в обоих фрагментах используете одну и ту же разметку - `fragment_login.xml`, а в неё нет `RecyclerView`. Внимательнее проверяйте код и будьте очень внимательны при копипасте

Comment: Спасиба большое.

Answer (score 3):

Это значит, что в строке

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

Такой вьюхи не было найдено.

Убедись, что в xml файле разметки именно такое id у RecyclerView

Comment: В `layout` указан именно такой `id`  `android:id="@+id/recycler_view"`

Comment: @FediaCholak, а в коде `R.id.rview` Все правильно вам подсказывают.